# Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script

Tags: python, html

I am beginner in CGI and trying to pass input from HTML to python (html file input to python file). i dont know where i am doing wrong. I am following tutorial from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm and for extra help i also looked at [Posting html form values to python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965646/posting-html-form-values-to-python-script) but failed. I am using windows 8 OS.

Here is my code: **test.py**

```
#!C:\Python27\python

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb 

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="search" action="/cgi-bintest.py" method="get">
Search: <input type="text" name="searchbox">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

On chrome: when i write `"http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.html"` it gives:

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

localhost
Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.12
```

Note: I have placed both files i.e test.py and test.html in "cgi-bin" is that correct? as i am coming from php, javascript etc background.

Kindly help plz if am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've configured your apache setup incorrectly (AND you have a typo in your html file). Put the HTML file in your document root (see your docroot setting) and the CGI in the `/cgi-bin/` directory.

Then in chrome, go to `http://localhost/test.html`

fyi -- the typo in your HTML file does not correctly reference your cgi-bin. Line 3 is missing a forward slash. It should be:

```
<form name="search" action="/cgi-bin/test.py" method="get">
```

Comment: u mean i shd place test.html in htdoc?

Comment: Check your apache configuration. In your `httpd.conf` will be setting called `docroot`. That is where to put your HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the .htaccess file at C:\xampp\htdocs\
.htaccess file is automatically create and go to the browser and refresh the page it will load.