# pass variables from html 5 form to python code

Tags: python, html, forms

I need help. I want to pass variables from html 5 form to python code. I found it can be done with django but it is recommended that I use html and javascript.
Any help please!

Comment: you can use Django website tutorial docs  understand working process.

Comment: @gaurav I have to use html and javaScript not Django

Comment: With html and javascript, it is not possible to send data to your python script

Comment: what about java ? @SanketVyawahare

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Posting html form values to python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965646/posting-html-form-values-to-python-script)

Comment: @SanketVyawahare, it is.

Comment: Why you want to go into complexity? if you want to send data to python, then use python at backend. Its is not tough. Flask can do it for you in very less time.

Comment: html and JS is client side so  when you want to pass variable python mean server side you have to use some framework or library to do that if Django is not necessary then i would suggest to you Flask framwork in python .  now why would you want to send variable to python or java ?

Comment: We will open HTML in browser... Browsers won't provide a RE for python. So You need to make your python code to be listening on some port over over http... To do that you can simply use http.server module. Instead you can use other popular web frameworks like django, fastapi, flask and many more which provides all boiler plates abstracted into simple options/functions/configuration. After making your you python code listening on some host you can do simple form submit and Ajax request from your Html

Comment: @OlvinRoght when I follow this example ,I get entire code of python in the browser when I click the submit button