# How to pass flask HTML form data into separate .py script, then display back on the same HTML page

Tags: python, html, flask

Very new to python/flask and actually to programming in general.

I'm trying to create a flask html form that will pull data from an API and take the user input and run it through a separate python script file named cityid.py. Then have it return the results of the cityid.py script back into the same HTML page, but below the input box.

End result would be something like this on the HTML page:

Enter your city: ______________
(submit button)

*results printed here from the cityid.py script*

Here's the form I have in my HTML file.

```
<form name="search" action="/cityid.py" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="city_input">
    <input type="submit1" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

within my cityid.py script I have the following to start off the script, referred to this question. [Posting html form values to python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965646/posting-html-form-values-to-python-script)

```
import cgi

def city_details():
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    city = form.getvalue('city_input')

#rest of the script below, but the city variable is what I need to be user input from the flask form
```

Here's what I have in the main.py file

```
@app.route("/city_details2", methods=['GET','POST'])
def city_details2():
    if request.method == "POST":
        return render_template("city_details2.html", city_details=city_details())
```

Now I can't seem to even start the flask web server because I get the following error:

`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str`

It's basically already trying to run the separate cityid.py script without having the user input first to get the city variable.

Anyone have an input on what I'm doing wrong here?  I suspect it's something wrong with the @app.route?  Or how do I get the user input first before running the cityid.py script?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm) is going to help you.

> Here is a simple URL, which passes two values to hello_get.py program using GET method. `/cgi-bin/hello_get.py?first_name=ZARA&last_name=ALI`
> Below is hello_get.py script to handle input given by web browser. We are going to use cgi module, which makes it very easy to access passed information
>
> ```
> import cgi, cgitb 
> # Create instance of FieldStorage 
> form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
> # Get data from fields
> first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
> last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')
> ```

**HTML :**

> ```
> <form action = "/cgi-bin/hello_get.py" method = "get"> 
> First Name: <input type = "text" name = "first_name">  <br />
> Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "last_name" />
> <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
> </form>
> ```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Looking at your code it looks the same as what I have in my city_details2.html and cityid.py file.  I would have thought once I run the main.py file it would at least start the website.  The error is stating that 'city' is empty (which it is because there isn't any user input yet)