# Analysis in python using form

Tags: python, html, css, forms

I have to create a form in python and input data from the user. Using that data I have to perform analysis. Single page website with the input-form, when a user submits the form, it will display prediction results based on the data. how would I do this?

Comment: I think you need to add more details on what you're trying to achieve, but I'm assuming you need to connect your html with python as database, you might want to check on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965646/posting-html-form-values-to-python-script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Posting html form values to python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965646/posting-html-form-values-to-python-script)